# Why is Copy a supertrait of Pod in the bytemuck crate?

Tags: rust

According to bytemuck's doc [here](https://docs.rs/bytemuck/latest/bytemuck/trait.Pod.html), `Pod` is only a marker trait. Its definition is as following:

```rust
pub unsafe trait Pod: Zeroable + Copy + 'static { }
```

My understanding of a "marker trait" is that: its purpose is to declare some types to have some traits (here I mean "trait" in English, a synonym of "characteristics") that cannot be described by functions/methods. In this way, others (especially the consumers of these types) know how to properly handle these types. For example, `Copy` is a marker trait. When marking a type as `Copy`, the Rust compiler knows when dealing `a = b` for this type, it should do a bitwise copy. `Send` is a also a marker trait. When marking, the compiler knows this type could be sent to another thread.

Come back to `Pod`. If I declare that my type is a `Pod`, why should I at least make my type a `Copy`? When I mark my type as `Pod`, I'm saying to `bytemuck`, "Hey, my type is a `Pod`. You can trust me without any doubt. My type is absolutely a `Pod`. You can now reinterpret some bytes as my type."

Is it because `bytemuck` wants to make sure any type that contains non-`Copy` types can't be marked as `Pod`? Since "A type is `Copy`" is indeed a **necessary but not sufficient condition** of "A type is `Pod`" (After all, how can a type be plain old data if it's even not `Copy`). In this way, for example, the developer won't accidentally include a non-`Copy` type (like `Vec<u8>` and `String`) in the custom struct.

If this is actually the reason, I'm still confused. I still need to mark an extremely large type as `Copy` only to mark it as `Pod`. The following struct is an example.

```rust
struct MyStruct {
    data: [u8; 10_000_000],
}
```

This is somewhat ridiculous. What if I accidentally trigger a bitwise copy of this type?

Isn't it a better idea not to make `Copy` a supertrait of `Pod`? I (as the code author) will take the full responsibility for every type that I mark as `Pod`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am not familiar with `bytemuck`'s internals, but I would guess this is a soundness requirement, as `bytemuck` certainly works with `unsafe` code to perform bit fiddling.

The actual specification of the `Copy` trait is that a type `T` can be `Copy` if a value `x: T` only "owns its bits" (as in Rust's ownership system). For instance, an integer is `Copy` because when you own an integer, you just own the bits that represent this integer, whereas when you own a `Box<i32>`, you don't just own the bits used to represent the box (which, in the end, is just a pointer). You also own what is pointed by the pointer.

A corollary of being `Copy` is that any value of a `Copy` type is that moving it is the same operation as `clone`ing it (which is why `Clone` is a supertrait of `Copy`). This is because moving a value in Rust is defined as a bitwise copy of the bits of the underlying representation, from one location to an other.

In particular, it is not true that having a type not being `Copy` prevents it from being bitwise copied: **every value can be implicitely bitwise-copied whenever it is moved**. So having your type which is a huge blob of data not being `Copy` does *not* prevent it from being bitwise copied around.

However, it is true that it is expected that `Copy` types are cheap to copy, because otherwise Rust prefers users having to explicitly write `clone`, to ensure that they consciously know they are doing an expensive operation.

For this reason, you might indeed not want to tag your type as `Copy`. To solve that problem, you could use the newtype pattern: create a type `struct MyPublicStructure(MyStructure)`, which does *not* implement `Copy`. Implement `Copy` and `Pod` for the inner type. Then, simply use that type when you need to do some bit fiddling, and convert back to `MyPublicStructure` when you don't need to do bit fiddling anymore. This way, you can explicitly highlight the parts of your code where you need pay attention that you might accidentally implicitly perform an expensive copy, and your public API is clean.

Comment: Thanks for answering! Could you please kindly provide an example for how to use the newtype pattern? To mark `PodMyStructure` implements as `Pod`, we should mark it `Copy` first. But we can't mark it as `Copy` because its content (whose type is `MyStructure`) is not marked as `Copy`.

Comment: @Yan yes, indeed, what I have suggested doesn't work, I messed up! I meant it the other way around: the public type is the newtype one, which *doesn't* implement `Copy`; and the inner type does. You pass around the public type, and when you need to do bit manipulations, you peek inside the public type. Is this correction enough, or would you need actual code?

Comment: Thanks I understand. Yes this should work I think. And to some degree, it indeed makes it harder to accidentally perform an expensive copy (it cannot completely prevent). Though I still think it's better to remove `Copy` as a supertrait of `Pod`. For now, seems that your approach is a good enough workaround. Really thanks for sharing this design pattern!

Comment: I'm not sure that having `Copy` as a supertrait is a sonudness requirement, because `Pod` is an unsafe trait -- therefore, this requirement could simply be documented along with the many other safety requirements of the trait. The crate authors could have simply said that you can only implement it on types that _could_ implement `Copy` regardless of whether they actually do implement it.

Comment: @cdhowie Yes I also think so.